# trouble removing .php extension from rackspace site htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rackspace

I am trying to remove the .php extensions from website which is being hosted on rackspace. I have this issue resolved already with my local using htacess, but the same solution doesnt work on rackspace.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com)$ // check for rackspace hosted domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/([^\.]+)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Rackspace does have special requirements like you must specify the domain in the RewriteRule or else rackspace will resolve to the root directory in the server instead.

The problem is I feed the url

domain.com/file

and it resolves to

domain.com/file.php

in the url. so how do I get rackspace not to add the .php extension in the url. Been trying to look up this issue but can only find solutions that are generic with htaccess, nothing specific to rackspace.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you add `http://hostname` it will redirect. Remove that.

Comment: Try last `RewriteRule` line as: `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]`

Comment: thanks for the reply but: "Rackspace does have special requirements like you must specify the domain in the RewriteRule or else rackspace will resolve to the root directory in the server instead." resolving to root directory causes unknown file path error. My local works fine with the /$1.php alone. I have tried that on rackspace

Comment: Is there a way to keep htaccess from redirecting? looking for a flag to add the RewriteRule, but cant find anything.

Comment: If you use `http://` in target then it can't be internal rewrite.

Comment: Are you hosting your web site on Rackspace Cloud Sites or Rackspace Cloud Servers?